# ListView: how to access a view from the list to change the background color?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that uses a custom string adapter so I can change the font and text type. However I want to have the selected item on the list to have a different background color than the other items.

I use the onItemClick listener and with that I can change the color of the selected item. But I don't know how to change the color of the previously selected option back. Here is the code:

```
    schemelist = new ListView(context);
    AuxClasses.CustomAdapter adapter = new AuxClasses.CustomAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Aux.FontMastermind,Aux.WhiteColor,14);
    adapter.addAll(Aux.SchemeList);
    schemelist.setAdapter(adapter);
    schemelist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(selection_color);
            //Change the background color of the previously selected item.

        }
    });
```

I figured I need to access the view of the previously selected Item, however I don't how access a view at a particular position.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

The easier & *not* recommended. To be honest, I don't even think that this will work. Well, you can give it a try:

Keep a class member `previouslySelectedView`.

```
View previouslySelectedView;

....

schemelist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
         if (previouslySelectedView != null) {
             previouslySelectedView.setBackgroundColor(ORIGINAL_COLOR);
         }

         view.setBackgroundColor(selection_color);

         previouslySelectedView = view;

    }
});
```

Recommended way:

Declare a variable `mSelectedPosition` inside your adapter.

```
int mSelectedPosition = -1;
```

Write a *setter* for `mSelectedPosition`:

```
public void setSelectedPosition(int pos) {
    mSelectedPosition = pos;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In your getView(....) method, check if current position is selected position:

```
if (curPos == mSelectedPosition) {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(selection_color);
} else {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(ORIGINAL_COLOR);
}
```

Now, all you need to do inside `onItemClick(....)`:

```
schemelist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        adapter.setSelectedPosition(i);
     }
});
```

That's it. You will need to declare `adapter` as `final`.

Comment: Thank you!!! I used the second approach worked like a charm. I had tried it. but I had never seen the  notifyDataSetChanged(); command.